# Creating a topic in Kafka only in one cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I run Docker file in [this location](https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-multiple-kafka-multiple.yml) which creates 3 clusters with 3 brokers. When I run docker ps, I can see 3 zookeeper and 3 kafka instances.

When I create a topic in one of the Kafka brokers (**0.0.0.0:9092**), and list broker topics, I see that topic listed in all brokers.

My expectation was to see that topic only under the broker I picked.

What am I missing?